# send Array of object via axios post in laravel vue

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js, post, axios

I am using vue and laravel. I getting an array of objects like this in console.log(array_of_obj) :

```
[…]
​
0: Object { id: Getter & Setter, employee_id: Getter & Setter, manual_id: Getter & Setter, … }
​
1: Object { id: Getter & Setter, employee_id: Getter & Setter, manual_id: Getter & Setter, … }
​
2: Object { id: Getter & Setter, employee_id: Getter & Setter, manual_id: Getter & Setter, … }
```

Each object contains my desired row data. Now I want to send it to Laravel controller via axios post request. How Can I do this?
I have tried this way:

```
let json=JSON.stringify(array_of_obj);
let post_data={json_data:json}
 store.dispatch('employees/EmployeeListDownloadPdf', post_data).catch(err => { console.error(err) })
```

In my vuex section:

```
EmployeeListDownloadPdf(ctx, employeeList) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    
                    axios({
                        url: '/api/employees/employeeListData',employeeList,
                        method: 'POST',
                        
                      })
                        //.then(response => resolve(response))
                        .then((response) => {
                            //console.log(response.data)
                            
                          });
                        //.catch(error => reject(error))
                })
            },
```

But in my controller I tried with following code but getting empty array.

```
dd(json_decode($request->all(),true));
dd(json_decode($request,true));
```

I want to get all data into my controller but can not accesss them now. How Can I do this?

Comment: I think you need to show us what the VueX action `employees/EmployeeListDownloadPdf` does. What you've shared doesn't show how your VueJS app sends the data to the server.

Comment: updated now. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `axios()` incorrectly: if you [read the docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig), the `employeeList` needs to be assigned to the data property in the object, i.e.:

```
axios({
    url: '/api/employees/employeeListData',
    data: employeeList,
    method: 'POST'
})
```

Comment: Now i Can get my data in Controller. Thanks a lot.